# join with condition Linq Query asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql

There is one to many relationship between leads -> activities.My requirement is to select a lead with respective only one activity which is recently added(w.r.t. activities.date_created)
Here is my code

```
public List<DOlead> getInactiveLeads(DateTime Start, DateTime End, DOuser user)
    {
        List<lead> ObjLeads = new List<lead>();
        List<DOlead> ObjLead = new List<DOlead>();
        //List<activity> actobj = _Context.activities;
        company comobj = _Context.companies.Where(x => x.id == user.company_id).FirstOrDefault();
        DateTime inactive = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-Convert.ToDouble(comobj.no_activity));
        ObjLead = (from le in _Context.leads
                    join leadstatus in _Context.leads_status on le.lead_status_id equals leadstatus.id
                    join act in _Context.activities on le.id equals act.lead_id 
                    where le.is_converted == false && le.date_created < inactive && le.date_created>Start && le.date_created<End 
                    select new DOlead
                    {
                        id = le.id,
                        title = le.title,
                        is_converted = le.is_converted,
                        street_address = le.street_address,


                    }).OrderByDescending(x => x.title).ToList();


        return ObjLead;

    }
```

But it gives matching data with repetitive leads.
kindly guide me?

Answer (score 0):

Your query is gonna return an item for every activity on a lead. So if a lead has 5 activities, you'll get 5 items returned.  Since you're only building up this DOlead object with properties from leads object, you're gonna get what looks liek a lot of repeats.

If you want to only see leads with recent activity, you should probably start from the list of activities in the window you care about, distinct the list of lead_ids, and then pull those leads.